# unit test does not coverage code of the method with swithcmap and tap

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a problem with testing method with switchmap, tap.

this code:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap((searchText) => this.searchable.search(searchText).pipe(
        tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
        catchError(() => {
          console.log('here')
          this.searchFailed = true;
          return of([]);
        }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    );
  }
```

here is my tests:

```
 it('should set searching to true', () =>{
    component.search(of('ASF')).subscribe(value =>{
      expect(!component.searchFailed);
    });
  })

  it('should call searchable metod', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'searchable').and.returnValue(of('TEST'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let textMock$ = of('TE')
    component.search(textMock$).subscribe(value => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  })

  it('should set searchFailed to true', () =>{
    spyOn(component, 'searchable').and.returnValue(throwError({ error: { status: 403 } }));
    component.search(of('TE')).subscribe(value =>{
      expect(this.searchFailed);
    });
  })
```

Tests run without errors, but test coverage does not take it. Also I dont know, how I can test tap()?

Thank you for tips.

Answer (score 2):

> Also I dont know, how I can test tap()?

You shouldn't test tap or any other operator. They are only a chain of functions which do not tell you anything about your function alone. What you want to test is the combination of all - that what you get out from what you give in. So you only should send values in and check the expected values you receive from this chain. The chain might call external ressources you can verify (expectToHaveBeenCalled), but thats it.

Assigning values within tap is an antipattern and shouldn't be done this way. Pending and failed searches can be described in other ways. With that being said, you might want to read about test driven design.

Also I suggest to test Observables without subscription with the use of marble https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I understand now about testing tap(). So I try to test only call spy. Why it doesnt coverage my code?

Comment: Well you only want 1 result emition, when test$ emits 2 same values or emits 2 values within 200ms. So for example `in: of('TE', 'TE')` results in an observable which emitted once.